# Unable to call Curried function from componentDidMount() in React component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have the following function in my action

```
export const fetchDeviceData = (deviceData: Object): ThunkAction => (dispatch: Dispatch, getState: GetState, axios: any) => {

    console.log('inside fetchDeviceData', deviceData);
    return dispatch(fetchDeviceDataAPI(axios, url, deviceData));

};
```

and I call it in the following way in the componentDidMount() block in my component

```
// type declaration (imported from a separate file)
export type DeviceReg = {
    [deviceData: Object]: {
        readyStatus: string,
        err: any,
        payload: Object,
    }
};

// Prop type declaration
type Props = {
    device_reg: DeviceRegType,
    fetchDeviceData: () => void,
}

componentDidMount() {
    const x = this.getDeviceData();
    console.log('header mount mobile', x);
    action.fetchDeviceData(x);
}

// The connector
const connector: Connector<{}, Props> = connect(
    ({ device_reg }: Reducer) => ({ device_reg }),
    (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
        fetchDeviceData: (deviceData) => dispatch(action.fetchDeviceData(deviceData)),
    }),
);
export default Header;
```

the issue is that the, fetchDeviceData(x) function is not getting called when I include the parameters `dispatch: Dispatch, getState: GetState, axios: any` in the function, but it works other wise. The imports and dependencies are not an issue as I have already verified them loads of times.

Any suggestions, hints or solutions will be of great help. Please let me know if you need any kind of clarification or context regarding my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share how you `connect` your component?

Comment: included some additional details in the edit. Please take a look.

Comment: looks like you should be calling this.props.fetchDeviceData(...)

Comment: not working, gives my a TypeError: this.props.fetchDeviceData is not a function. If I call it from props, do I need to pass this function anywhere? Sorry, still new to react. Actually this is a part of the Header component which needs to called only once, so I haven't made a route for it. And when I log this.props, it gives me an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

Can your try removing `axios: any` from `dispatch: Dispatch, getState: GetState, axios: any` ?

I think there's supposed to be only dispatch and getState, because that's what gets injected by redux-thunk.

Comment: already tried that, didn't work. The only case where the control went inside the function was when I removed all three parameters (dispatch, getState and axios). Can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your connect code to use the object form:

```
connect(
    <yourMapStateToProps>,
    {
        fetchDeviceData: actions.fetchDeviceData,
    }     
)
```

this should make `fetchDeviceData` available as a prop for you to call.

Also, try to remove the `axios` argument from the function signature leaving only `dispatch` and `getState`

Comment: okay, will try that. but can you tell me why this approach isn't working? Is it not right to call a function directly in the component ?

Comment: no, actions should be `dispatch`ed (unless they are bound via `connect` as I've described above)